# Splash screen in iOS games

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, loading, startup, splash-screen

I know there is a [HIG](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/LaunchImages.html) about launch images, and the primary (and only) purpose of an launch image is to give users the impression that  app is fast and responsive.

But this is more usual for applications (weather application for example), not for the games. Every game almost always has splash screen and that's how things should be in the games (or that's just me :).

In many games it can be seen that launch image is used as a splash screen, or promotional material for showing things like logos... So what would be a proper way for a game to have a splash screen? Is it better to follow the HIG and make an "screenshot" of user interface (without elements, just background) so that user really have an impression that app is loaded instantly and after launch image is removed, to show a splash screen? Or as another option, to use launch image as a splash screen(like in many games)?

There is a problem when using launch image as a splash screen because on newer devices loading time take just about second or less and I think that some kind of delaying launch image is not a good solution. So what is the preferred way to having a splash screen before game starts, what do you guys recommend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am kind of going off of what Sven said.

Don't have a splash image because it isn't really needed unless you want your user to sit there and stare at your logo (as Sven said it is kind of rude =) )

When your game launches provide your own version of a splash screen with a loading bar "if" needed. Now this only makes sense if you are talking about going into some sort of crazy menu that requires a lot of preloading. For most games you are on some sort of menu after launch and most of the time the loading of game resources doesn't happen until after the user decides to actually start a game. You may start loading resources in the background but they are not needed for the menu so there is no point in preventing the user from seeing your menu or interacting with it.

Starting a game is a time that would be more appropriate to show a loading screen (or splash type screen) with a progress bar if your background loading isn't finished or you are just now starting to load assets.

Hopefully that makes sense and is helpful.

Comment: Yeah, it makes sense a lot, especially if you are not loading everything at once in memory and keep it there trough whole app lifecycle. But if you do, like in Apple's adventure game, which is a pattern I've partially followed then splash screen/or logo/or something while preloading resources in background thread at app launch is needed. But I will try to load everything lazily. Thanks for reply!

Comment: @Whirlwind If you don't load everything lazily I would load just what you need for the menu and start loading the rest on the background thread right away. The only trick would be to check if it was done when the user goes to play the game. If everything hasn't finished loading show a loading screen then. You will likely be done preloading, but you will want to check if you are. With that being said I am a big fan of lazily loading resources. I wouldn't want to load everything for every level and so forth all at once. =)

Answer (score 2):

If you must have a splash screen then put it in the launch image, don't make the user wait for the splash screen to disappear while the app is doing nothing - that is just rude to the player. Nobody wants to stare at your logo (no matter how nice it is) while they could be playing your game.

What would be OK is to display your splash screen together with an animated loading indicator while your game loads resources on a background queue if you must have a long loading phase. Streaming resources as needed while the game plays still would be much better.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yeah, I agree that letting the player stare at the logo is not the way to go. But As I said, on newer devices launch images is shown for about second or less sometimes, so the splash screen(which is launch image actually) won't be properly shown...And if using progress bar, splash screen has to stay there until resources are loaded in the background thread. And that is not possible if using launch image because ,launch image is removed when appDidFinishLaunching is executed. Can you describe more closely that sequence when splash screen is shown and progress bar is added?

Answer (score 1):

The launchscreen is an artifact back from the early iOS. Usually an app is required to save its state and restore itself to the state when loading. That's why iOS uses a screenshot of the last state during launch.

If you don't support restoring the state of your app then there is only one solution. Handle the app launch quickly as possible and display the splash screen on your own.

Edit to clarify:
Just finish the the app delegate as quickly you can.

`- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions`
Display then a splashscreen on your own. Use a NSTimer, UITapGesture or UIButton to dismiss - or whatever you want. :)

Comment: Thanks for pointing about restoring the state ! I'll keep that in mind. I've totally forgot about that feature, but actually that doesn't address to my question. I am talking about first launch (startup sequence) and trying to understand what is the good way to show an logo, do loading stuff (in the background) make app look responsive and follow the HIG :) If all that is possible :)

Comment: Then the second paragraph in my answer is for you. Just finish the the app delegate: - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions as quickly as passible and display a splash screen on your own. (nstimer, touch or button to dismiss -whatever you want)